# Div goes down when paze is browser zoom

Tags: css, html

```
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
      <div style="width:1016px;">
        <div style="width:8px; height:100px; background:red; width:8px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style=" float:left; border:#ccc solid 1px; height:100px; padding:20px; width:958px;">
            testing 1016=8+1000+8
        </div>
        <div style="background:red; height:100px; width:8px; float:left;"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In My html/css why last div goes down when i browser zoom.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Your last div is empty, so it shouldn't be a problem for it to go down. Take that into account when reformulating your question as an actual question.

Comment: Anyway, the answer to your question is, it doesn't. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: My question is last div with red background goes down when browser resize to 25%. and it shouldnt be

Comment: @MrLister i know i am missing something but i m not getting it. plz help me to point out to my mistake.

Comment: Like I said, the divs don't move when you resize the browser window. unless you mean when you _zoom_ the browser window. Then you will get round off errors in pixels, so the inner three divs added up will not be exactly the width of the outer div. (For example, three 33px wide boxes in a 99px container. When zoomed to 75%, the inner boxes will be 25px each, while the container will only be 74px!)

Comment: @MrLister: yes thats i got problem when zoom browser window. thanx but Can you give me solution for than as practical becoz i didnt get solution from you answer i still getting problme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as I said in my comment, is the rounding error in pixels when zooming.

Simple example: if you have three 33px wide boxes in a 99px container, and you zoom out to 75%, the boxes will be (rounded) 25 pixels wide, while the container will be 74 pixels wide. And that doesn't fit!

```
.container {
    width:99px;
}
.child {
    float:left; width:31px; height:31px; 
    border:1px solid #666;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pc3kq/). (Note however, that different browsers have the problem on different zoom factors. Apparently, they don't all round off in the same way. Oh well, at least we can observe that there's a problem.)

So, what can we do? Well, there are a number of solutions:

1. Make the container a bit wider, or remove its width constraint altogether, so that it is as wide as the window. Then the boxes will always fit. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc3kq/3/).
2. As an alternative, make the container an inline block instead of giving it a width; that will make sure it fits snugly around its content.

   ```
   .container {
       display:inline-block;
   }
   ```

   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc3kq/5/)
3. Give the rightmost box a negative margin, large enough to offset the rounding error. If there's nothing you need to display to the right of the container, you can make this margin as large as you want, it won't make a difference.

   ```
   .child:last-child {
       margin-right:-100%
   }
   ```

   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc3kq/4/).

And there are more solutions, but I'm sure these will get you started. Good luck!

Comment: its appreciated
but i need width in pixel as well :(
As in my give question/example if i remove border:#ccc solid 1px; from middle div then its working fine but i need it as well also :(

Comment: Do you mean that none of the solutions work for you?

Comment: No its not solution for my problem. I just cant get why div goes down

if i remove border:#ccc solid 1px; from my middle div and zoomout at any level, its working fine but i need border also so its not working.

Comment: Then you must explain what requirements you have. Apparently you haven't given me enough information to work with. Based on what you wrote in your question, these 3 solutions all work fine.

Comment: Here html/css i m using in page
In this html/css all value would be same for border and width as i needed. You can just change for height and background-color if you need







<div style="width:1016px;">

         <div style="background:red; height:100px; width:8px; float:left;">8</div>

            <div style=" border:#ccc solid 1px; height:100px; width:958px; padding:20px; float:left;">

            testing 1016=8+1000+8
            </div>

            <div style="background:red; height:100px; width:8px; float:left;">8</div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

Comment: And also i have try with 

box-sizing: border-box;  

but its causing another issue in page so dont waste your time with this css

Comment: That's the same as you already had in the question. You have not told me WHY none of the solutions work for you.

Comment: Ohhh Sorry Mr.Lister its wokring i have try your 
http://jsfiddle.net/pc3kq/3/
example
Thank you very much

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40318/discussion-between-nilesh-and-mr-lister)

Comment: Hey can you check below link i have update its not wokring

http://jsfiddle.net/nileshkevadiya/y9VAF/

i have just add width to your container div

Comment: That is because 1) in that fiddle you're not using any of my suggested solutions, and 2) you're trying to cram 1020 pixels of content into a 1016 pixel wide container.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nileshkevadiya/y9VAF/12/

In this exmaple i have try with 1020px also but facing same issue while zoomout and what i hv missing from your suggestion